# Hibernate -How to exclude a column while saving

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to save data in my primary and child table and this call my.domain.client.model.Employee emp = new Employee();  creates a select statement that includes the object wslog. This does not exists in database and is causing error as "invalid identifier". I used transient and it still uses the column to create select statement. How to resolve this issue?

Service Code

```
    my.domain.client.model.Wslog wsLog = new Wslog();
    wsLog.setRecords_rcvd(getRecords_rcvd());
    wsLogRepository.save(wsLog);
    List<my.domain.client.model.Employee> empList = new ArrayList<my.domain.client.model.Employee>();
    for (my.domain.client.model.Employee emp : wsLog.getEmployees()) {
        my.domain.client.model.Employee emp = new Employee();            
        emp.setID(getEid());
        emp.setEname(getEname());
        empList.add(emp);
    }
    wsLog.setEmployees(empList);
    wsLogRepository.save(wsLog);
```

Hibernate MODEL

```
    WsLog(Primary)
    @Column(name = "logid") //has sequence
    private long logid;
    @Column(name = "totrecords")
    private long totrecords;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "emp") 
    private List<Emp> emplist;

    Emp(Child)
    @Column(name = "logid")
    private long logid;
    @Column(name = "eid")
    private Long eid;
    @Column(name = "ename")
    private String ename;
    @JoinColumn(name = "logid")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Wslog wslog;
```

Comment: Can you just delete the annotation and make it a simple field, not column? Am I right - you want just a plain property in entity?

Comment: Issue resolved. I removed the  below and it worked.                                                    @JoinColumn(name = "logid")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Wslog wslog;

Comment: Most of the oneToMany examples are based on the model I have  shown in my main post. Still not sure why it tries to insert or select on the object column(wslog). Any one who can help here?